# Invalid roslaunch XML syntax: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: u'/opt/ros/melodic/share/gazebo_ros/launch/launch/gazebo_empty_world.launch'

Tags: ros-melodic

[image: Rosanswers logo]

launch file:

```
<launch>

  <arg
  name="model" 
  default="$(find kct_robot)/urdf/kct_robot.xacro"
  />

 
    <arg name="world"
         default="$(find gazebo_plugins)/test2/worlds/empty.world"/>
<include file="$(find gazebo_ros)/launch/launch/gazebo_empty_world.launch">
        
    </include>
    
<param name="robot_description" command="$(find xacro)/xacro --inorder $(arg model)" />

 <node
    name="joint_state_publisher"
    pkg="joint_state_publisher"
    type="joint_state_publisher" />
  <node
    name="robot_state_publisher"
    pkg="robot_state_publisher"
    type="state_publisher" />

  <node
    name="spawn_model"
    pkg="gazebo_ros"
    type="spawn_model"
    args="-x 1.3644922
      -y 3.0975677
      -z 0.0
      -R 0.0
      -P 0.0
       -Y -3.14
 -urdf  
    
  -param robot_description -model robot_base"
    
    output="screen" />

</launch>
```

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/344778/invalid-roslaunch-xml-syntax:-%5Berrno-2%5D-no-such-file-or-directory:-u%27/opt/ros/melodic/share/gazebo_ros/launch/launch/gazebo_empty_world.launch%27/) by [TVJ](https://answers.ros.org/users/51875/tvj/) on ROS Answers with karma: 1 on 2020-02-21

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

try:

Your File has .../launch/launch/... in it, doesnt seem normal to me.

---

Originally posted by [Dragonslayer](https://answers.ros.org/users/38812/dragonslayer/) with karma: 574 on 2020-02-22

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [TVJ](https://answers.ros.org/users/51875/tvj/) on 2020-02-24**:
Thank you. I solved the problem